# Number Fields Generated by Fourier Coefficients of Modular Forms

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

We know that for every normalized Hecke eigenform $f$, its Fourier coefficients generate a number field. I wonder if we have an "inverse Galois" type conjecture regarding which number fields can be generated in this way. Moreover, do we have some sort of statistical results/conjectures regarding the frequency of a number field appearing as a field generated by the Fourier coefficients of an eigenform? I would like to apologize in advance if this is a naive question.

Comment: First, these fields are either totally real fields $E$ or CM (totally imaginary extension of $E$), so you certainly can't get every field. Second, if you restrict to weight two, then you obtain abelian varities of $\mathrm{GL}_2$ type with endomorphisms by an order in $E$. This corresponds to a point on a Hilbert modular variety for $E$. For all but finitely many $E$ these have general type, so there no reason to expect that even when $E$ is totally real there should be any form $f$. Finally, if you assume the weight is large enough, there's no reason to even expect that $\mathbf{Q}$ occurs.

Comment: @user297024 Thank you very much for your comment. I just found Ribet's article in Antwerp V that proved these fields must be totally real or CM.